# swing panel resizable gap

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm using eclipse and windowsbuilder, for making java gui application. I'm having a trouble in maintaining the padding of the components in swing panel. I'm using the group layout in the windowbuilder designer to position components. But sadly I'm not able to maintain the the padding when the window gets re-sized.

[image: window on normal size]

Normal window

[image: Window on maximized]
window when re-sized or maximized

When the window is re-sized, I wish to make my app automatically re-size the horizontal and vertical gaps like in the third image so that component padding will be maintained correctly.
[image: Window padding i wish to have]

The code:

```
public myframe() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(166)
                    .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                    .addContainerGap(169, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(37)
                    .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                    .addContainerGap(192, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You may be looking for [`MiGLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/), which permits [*Specifying Gaps*](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

i ve found the solution for this one: :)
just replace .addGap() with .addContainerGap() it worked fine after doing that.